# Trello board is missing description button

Tags: trello, trello-organization, trello-boards

All I want to do is edit the description of my boards. However the little pencil icon that used to appear on all boards now only appears on boards that have descriptions.

Here is an example without a button:

[image]

How can I change the board description?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Trello is phasing out board descriptions. The button is no longer available for new boards or boards without descriptions. The problem was that most people didn’t know about the feature, and making it more prominent or further investing in it didn’t seem valuable. The team recommends adding a card on the top left that says “Hey, look here for information about this board!” (which is what our team was doing anyway, despite knowing very well about the description button).

For the record, I work on Trello.

Comment: You can tell your colleagues, I am really disappointed with that decision... Having such a description doesn't really seem like a huge feature that needs to be promoted to people who don't need it, so even that explanation is pretty strange. What would have been the cost to carry around this simple feature further down the road?
But those users who needed and saw it, used it. Now it's gone, and the idea from the FAQ to put a card somewhere(where?! is it todo, done, or in progress?!) is just flawed.

Comment: Funny, on a product honcho'd by the man who wrote, "Unfortunately, it's never the same 20%. Everybody uses a different set of features." http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000020.html :-D

Comment: I was using the board description as a place for custom metadata (think project and client IDs linking a board to external systems), which is annoying it's not available any more. Is there an alternate place for custom metadata / properties at the board level these days?

Comment: @Henning Absolutely agree. Having to create a separate list to put your description card in is such a waste of space